# Arrow points are located on the file on gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I know by this command I can create one arrow on gnuplot.

```
set arrow from 0,0 to 1,1
```

But the problem is this which I want to create a set of arrows. which located on **file.data**. the x1, y1, x2 and y2 are not in the data file I just out them to show them better

```
x1  y1   x2   y2 

80 42.34 75 50.34
75 50.34 65 50.34
65 50.34 60 58.34
60 58.34 65 66.34
65 66.34 60 75
```

ius there any way to pass this file to gnuplot. in order to create an arrow from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can plot with the `with vectors` style. With your data file, this would be:

```
plot "data" using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors
```